# How use AD FS token in console application

Tags: c#, console-application

i have AD FS server, console app and simple web site wher i can sign in with my domain account.
In my console application i get token from STS. Now, I want log with him to web site (i want check token).

How should I use this token in WebClient, WebApiClient and WCF?
I tried Opened channel in WCF with this token and download page using WebClient but i get log page.

this token is inportant 2 weeks, how cann I cancel this token earlier?

this is my code to get token (works):

```
string userName = "login";
string password = "pass";
string adfsAdr = @"https://domain/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed";
string webPage = @"https://MyAspNetAppAdrs.com";

var factory = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannelFactory(
    new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
    new EndpointAddress(adfsAdr));

factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
if (_factory.Credentials != null)
{
    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
}

var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
{
    RequestType = WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
    AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(webPage),
    KeyType = WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer,
};

var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst);
```

Comment: Did you manage to progress this at all? I am attempting the exact same thing and also finding this very confusing.